# USART communication on STM32L476G Discovery

Tags: c, stm32, gpio, usart, stm32ldiscovery

I have two boards: a NUCLEO-F411RE and a STM32L467G Discovery.

I need to make a Virtual Com connection between my STM32L467G Discovery and my PC.

For the NUCLEO : The USART2 is connected to ST-Link, so i can communicate with my PC with USART on USB. So, I enable the GPIO**A** and USART2 Clock. After that, i configure my GPIO**A** to link Ports 2 and 3 on the USART2, and it works well! I can receive some characters on my PC.

For the STM32L467G Discovery : The STM32L467G Discovery has the USART2 on Port 2 and 3 on GPIO**A** too. But, in the documentation, they say that the USART2 is connected with the ST-Link with USART2 on Port 5 and 6 in GPIO**D**. So, i have modify my souce code but i can't receive anything in my computer..

Check my sources:

Main.c

```
#include "stm32l4xx.h"
#include "stm32l476g_discovery.h"


UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
void configure_system_clock(void);

int main(void)
{

    HAL_Init(); // HAL Init

    configure_system_clock(); // Configure Clock


    __GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE(); // Enable GPIOD clock
    __USART2_CLK_ENABLE(); // Enable USART2 Clock


    huart2.Instance = USART2;
    huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
    huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    HAL_UART_Init(&huart2);



            /**USART2 GPIO Configuration
            PA2     ------> USART2_TX
            PA3     ------> USART2_RX
            */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    char *msg = "Hello YOU\n\r";

          HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)msg, 15, 0xFFFF);
      while (42);
}

void configure_system_clock(void)
{
    RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    __PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE2);

    RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 6;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV7;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
    HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct);

    RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
    HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2);
}
```

This code works fine on the Nucleo NUCLEO-F411RE (but with GPIO**A** and port 2 and 3).

On my STM32L467G Discovery, that code totaly fail, with GPIO**D** port 5 and 6 && with GPIO**A** port 2 and 3.

I can't see the problem, can you help me please?

Comment: 1) That STlib is awful and just adds bloat, but no true abstraction. 2) STlink is a JTAG interface, not sure how that is related to serial communication. Normally you need some kind of USBSerial adapter like FT232. 3) stack overflow is no remote debugging service. See [ask] and provide a [mcve] along with a **specific** problem. Ensure your hardware is correctly setup and configured. Until then all bets are off. Use a debugger.

Comment: @Olaf I believe some embedded ST-Link implementations, like the ones on certain Discovery boards, include a serial sidechannel.

Comment: @duskwuff: Just checked the F407 and F429 boards. You are right, the latter also has that side-channel. As it is newer, it very well might have become an enhancement to the family. Anyway, OP still has not proved the hardware as such is correctly configured.

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing the UART in the main and that could be ok, but you are not catching the way HAL libraries want you to initialize the peripheral's pin.
You should do that in the HAL_UART_MspInit() function you can find in stm32f4_hal_msp.c file.

Your main should look like this

```
HAL_Init(); // HAL Init

configure_system_clock(); // Configure Clock

huart2.Instance = USART2;
huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
HAL_UART_Init(&huart2); 

 HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)msg, 15, 0xFFFF);
```

Then in your HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart) you should have something like this:

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
if(huart->Instance==USART2)
{
 /* Peripheral clock enable */
 __USART2_CLK_ENABLE();
 __GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

/**USART2 GPIO Configuration  */
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART2;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART2_IRQn, 0, 1);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART2_IRQn);
}
```

Pay attention to "GPIO_PULLUP", I suggest you to config GPIO like this for UART.
You also have to define the UART Handler in your stm32f4_it.c file:

```
void USART2_IRQHandler(void)
{
 HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Generate the startup using STM-Cube**

[Please look at this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938261/rs232-uart-on-stm32f4-discovery-stm32f429zit6-with-hal-library/34990007#34990007) I gave just this week to someone in a similar situation. I took the challenge since I have been experiencing the same frustrations.

I have found it always best to work at the highest possible level when starting a project, regardless. I want to be in a position to leverage technical advances as they occur.

Portable, well documented, high level applications are easily maintained and can be quickly ported to newer processors and architectures.

Optimisation at the bits and bytes level comes later to meet specific performance targets not already met.

By concentrating on the high level solution, new approaches to the algorithm often yield better performance advantages than low level optimisations.

Removing bloated initialisation sequences may save a few hundred bytes of startup code and shave a few microseconds, but startup is seldom on the critical path.

Having a working product on the shelf a month before the opposition can be worth your whole business.

If blinding speed is needed, migrate to higher powered architectures before you begin e.g. STM7 series.

A profiler will quickly yield remaining bottlenecks. These can be optimised, using the high level implementation as specification.

Yes, STM libs (and many other libs e.g. sprintf) are big and bloated, yes they do not address everyone's requirements. But they are nonetheless useful and constantly being improved outside of my budget.

The cost of development is measured in man hours, save them.

Start by configuring everything in CUBE and generating the code, use as many of the features of the chipset and libraries as you can to provide the best solution at a high level.

Build up a library of second layer solutions and optimisation you can reuse in other applications.

The recent upgrade to STMCube and HAL libraries corrected a number of problems I experienced in the past. Not perfect, but very usable and worthwhile. Improvement is ongoing.

Spend the bulk of your time developing the application, rather than fiddling round with unnecessary low level optimisation.

This tends to make your boss happy - even if your only boss is the bank manager.

Hopefully the problems you (we) experienced are now a thing of the past.

Comment: What is `.ioc` file? Agree with the rest :)

Comment: @i486 an .ioc template is the file STM-Cube creates and maintains detailing the configuration you set up I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Can you try to condense your answer a bit? As it stands you're kind of rambling -- your personal history as a developer, while interesting, isn't germane here.

Comment: @duskwuff - thanks for the comment - appreciated, OK now?